# H2O Decision Tree

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, decision-tree, h2o

I'm watching an H2O demo, but one of the code lines are cut off, and I have no clue what is supposed to be in the rest.

[image: image of code]

the gv_call assignment is cut off. Does anyone know what is supposed to be in the rest. I'm not familiar with the packages used.

Answer (score 1):

The complete java command call is

java -cp h2o.jar hex.genmodel.tools.PrintMojo --tree 0 -i "path/to/model.zip" -o model.gv -f 20 -d 3

where the -f is for fontsize, -d is for number of decimal points and they are optional.  To convert this into a subprocess call in Python, the gv_call is probably this:

gv_call=" ".join(["java", "-cp", h2o_jar_path, "hex.genmodel.tools.PrintMojo", "--tree", str(tree_number), "-i", mojo_path, "-o", gv_file_path, "-f", str(20), "-d", str(3)])